# How to exclude one empty element from displaying in XML output (XSLT 1.0)

Tags: xslt-1.0

I'm looking for a way to prevent a specific empty tag with no attribute from displaying if it’s null. I've only been able to find solutions where it's applied to the whole XSLT document which is not what I need. I need to only have a few empty tags I do not want displayed.

**ETA:**
An "empty element" to me is where it displays like `<Nm></Nm>` in the output and no text shows between the tags.

I have two different versions: One that does contain a child element, one that does not.

For the element with a child, this is what it looks like, and if `<ClrSysMmbId>` has no text between tags, display neither `<ClrSysMmbId>` or `<MmbId>`:

```
<ClrSysMmbId> <-- Remove if null 
    <MmbId/>  <-- Remove if null
</ClrSysMmbId>
```

```
<Cdtr> 
    <Nm>Institution Name</Nm> 
    <PstlAdr> 
        <PstCd>12345</PstCd> 
        <TwnNm>Town</TwnNm> 
        <CtrySubDvsn/> <-- Remove if null 
        <Ctry>JP</Ctry> 
        <AdrLine>123 Imaginary Drive</AdrLine> 
    </PstlAdr> 
    <CtctDtls/>
</Cdtr>
```

Should display like:

```
<Cdtr> 
    <Nm>Institution Name</Nm> 
    <PstlAdr> 
        <PstCd>12345</PstCd> 
        <TwnNm>Town</TwnNm> 
        <Ctry>JP</Ctry> 
        <AdrLine>123 Imaginary Drive</AdrLine> 
    </PstlAdr> 
    <CtctDtls/>
</Cdtr>
```

I tried this on the `<CtrySubDvsn>` element:

```
<xsl:if test="not(CtrySubDvsn='')">
    <CtrySubDvsn>
    <xsl:value-of select="SupplierorParty/Address/State" />
    </CtrySubDvsn>
</xsl:if>
```

It returns no errors, but still prints like so:

```
<Cdtr>
    <Nm>Institution Name</Nm>
        <PstlAdr>
        <PstCd>12345</PstCd>
        <TwnNm>Town</TwnNm>
        <CtrySubDvsn/>
        <Ctry>JP</Ctry>
        <AdrLine>123 Imaginary Drive</AdrLine>
        </PstlAdr>
    <CtctDtls/>
</Cdtr>
```

Comment: Please define "empty element ": (1) does not have child elements; (2) does not have attributes; (3) does not have text; a combination of above ... ?? --- Note also that the output you show is VERY different from the input.

Comment: My apologies, this is my first time using XSLT so I'm unfamiliar with the terminology. I've added more details to my question.

Comment: You need to learn at least the basic terms of XML structure, otherwise it's not possible to communicate.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the `CtrySubDvsn` element when it does not have any attributes or child nodes (i.e. elements, text nodes, comments or processing instructions) while keeping everything else as is, you can do:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CtrySubDvsn[not(@*|node())]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you apply multiple templates to a stylesheet?

Comment: Sorry, your question makes no sense. You do not apply templates to a stylesheet. A stylesheet contains one or more templates (2 in my example) that are applied to the input XML.